Why do so many of the possible UTF-8 encoding not correspond to a UTF-8 codepoint?
This table summarizes UTF-8's variable-width encoding scheme.

After noticing that not all the available 2-byte encodings are used, I extended the table as shown below, and saw that this was the case for 3-byte and 4-byte encodings as well (delta > 0).
| number of bytes | bits available for encodings | number of available encodings | number of codepoints                                | delta  = # avail encodings - # codepoints |
|-----------------|------------------------------|-------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------|
| 1               |          7                   |  2^7 =       128              |       0x80 -    0x00 =             8*16 =       128 |       128 -       128 =         0         |
| 2               | 5+1*6 = 11                   | 2^11 =     2,048              |     0x800 -    0x080 =    8*16^2 - 8*16 =     1,920 |     2,048 -     1,920 =       128         |
| 3               | 4+2*6 = 16                   | 2^16 =    65,536              |  0x1_0000 -    0x800 =    16^4 - 8*16^2 =    63,488 |    65,336 -    63,488 =     2,048         |
| 4               | 3+3*6 = 21                   | 2^21 = 2,097,152              | 0x11_0000 - 0x1_0000 = 0x10_0000 = 16^5 = 1,048,576 | 2,097,152 - 1,048,576 = 1,048,576         |

Is there a reason that so many encodings are unused?

The unused codepoints are put aside for future batches

0x87F instead of 0x7FF no, check bit pattern for 7 (111) and 8 (1000)

@IłyaBursov correct me if I'm wrong, but 0x880 - 0x080 = 0x800 = 8*(16^2) = 8*((2^4)^2) = 8*(2^(4*2)) = 8*(2^8) = (2^3)*(2^8) = 2^11 = 2048.

0x087F would be 0b0000_1000 0b0111_1111 which would not be a valid 2-byte encoding

0x07FF would be 0b0000_0111 0b1111_1111 which would also not be a valid 2-byte encoding

Or would the 0x07FF codepoint correspond to an encoding of 0b110_(111)[11] 0b10_[111111]? The (111) represents the 7 and the [11][111111] represents the FF.

Is the intent of the question basically: Given (for example) 2 bytes, why are only 11 bits used when it would be possible to potentially use more (at least 14) if the encoding was different?

@joseville codepoints are consecutive, so codepoint, but their encodings are not, so codepoint 0x7FF is last code point which can be encoded as 2 bytes 110_111_11 10_111111

Thanks for explaining! So the first 2-byte codepoint is U+0080 which is encoded as 110_000_10 10_00_0000. So encodings from 110_000_00 10_00_0000 to 110_000_01 10_11_1111 (inclusive) are unused.

Note: if you want more density we had UTF-1, but UTF-8 had clear advantage, and we (and browsers) uses often also to detect encoding: The more characters you have some bytes with values > 127, the more you are sure it if UTF-8 if you can decode it with UTF-8 (very probably other encoding will fail).

A key feature of UTF-8 is self-synchronization. You can jump into the middle of a UTF-8 stream at any point and figure out where the next character begins. This is because many values cannot be the first byte of a character. A side effect of this is that many possible byte sequences are invalid, so the encoding is not as dense as it could be (requires more bytes than the minimum), but it makes every sequence unambiguous. This is even true if individual bytes are lost or corrupted. The decoder can always find the next character starting point and recover. This is not true of other multi-byte encoding schemes like UTF-16 or Shift-JIS which can be difficult to resynchronize if there are errors.
The particular approach of encoding the character length in the first byte similarly reduces ambiguity in the face of dropped bytes in the stream or corruption. If you decode a start byte that indicates that this is a 3-byte character, followed by another start byte (rather than a continuation byte), the decoder can know that the previous character is corrupted. This leading length-indicator can also allow algorithms to skip over a given number of characters without decoding them.
Again, these benefits come at a size cost. For ASCII, the size cost is zero, and it's pretty modest for Latin-based scripts. Compared to previous national systems, it imposes about a 50% cost on Asian encodings (usually 3 bytes rather than 2), and generally doubles the size of Cyrillic, Arabic, Hebrew, and Greek (generally 2 bytes rather than 1). But the benefit is that there's one system that works universally and can mix scripts, and has the above-mentioned synchronization benefits. So it's become pretty much ubiquitous despite the size cost.

Thanks! So, for example, for the 2-byte encodings, the following 128 encodings are unused: 110_000_00 10_00_0000 to 110_000_01 10_11_1111 (inclusive). And the reason is because (some or all of?) these encodings would not allow "self-synchronization"? Seems like continuation bytes always begin w/ 10. Is all that's needed for self-synchronization is to determine whether a byte is a continuation byte or not? I'd imagine there's probably more sophisticated stuff going on.

@joseville: some combinations were used in UTF-8 (first version). Because of UTF-16, and success of Unicode, UCS (or better ISO) decided also to restrict maximum number of codepoints. But in past you could encode all 31-bit UCS codepoints using UTF-8 (and with more then 4 bytes), now we use only for UTF-8. -- But you will notice other problems: a single character (< 128) can be written (illegally as 2, 3 or 4 byte sequences). Decoders may/should find such case and report errors (security implication)

See last paragraph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#FSS-UTF for first point the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_sequences_and_error_handling for the overlong sequences.
